# Can i go to university without finished high school?

Tags: university

I wasn't sure if this would be off-topic or not.

Basically i have half finished high school here in Slovenia, it's slightly different here, i went to 3+2 program. I have finished 3 years but i don't wish to continue the extra 2 years, especially because they're not teaching me anything, in 5th year they teach about programming stuff i knew when i was a first year. And the extra two years would earn me a diploma for finished high school, not sure how the 3 years are called in English. So instead of wasting 2 years i thought if i could even apply for University in UK? I have a friend who lives in UK which would make it easier to move, but my question is if i can even apply? I've seen undergraduate courses and the requirements, but nothing there can apply to me? Or at least i'm not sure, is there some kind of exam that i can take or something similar?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you receive a diploma at the end of the first 3 years? Does this qualify you for higher education in Slovenia? If not, I would be surprised if it was sufficient for other countries. You could always investigate by contacting a university abroad.
If you **really** think the extra 2 years don't teach you anything new and you know it all, is it possible to enter the final exams early?
From my experience, the first year(s) of university hit you like a brick even if you finish high school. You can use 2 years of 'boring' school for preparation (self-study, enroll in courses at a local uni).

Comment: Yes, in some countries. See my answer here [https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/87614/phd-or-msc-without-undergraduate-degree/87619#87619]  that also applies to your case.

Comment: @ShakeBaby The OP seems to not want to finish secondary education, while your example refer to finish who did not finish their BA. Those are very different things.

Comment: Homeschooling is widespread in the US; there is definitely some sort of pipeline for homeschooled kids to enroll in undergrad studies (probably involving SAT exams and the likes). While I don't know anything UK-specific, I wouldn't be surprised if something like this applies to you; the question must have arisen at some point for US->UK expats that were homeschooled.

Comment: @MaartenBuis Yes, but there are examples of that too.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry but no, you can't. Every respectable university requires a high-school diploma (or equivalent degree) for students to enroll. Exceptions are extremely rare and apply only to highly gifted students in certain subjects.

However, you can self-study in your free time with more advanced textbooks and online courses. If your home-town has a university, you may be able to attend some lectures as a guest, without being formally enrolled.

Comment: Thanks. So it's either eating up extra 2 years or self-study programming and go to work directly. I'll look up if i can attend as a guest, that would be amazing.

Answer (score 1):

There are a small number of distance learning universities that will take students on without formal qualifications, probably one of the most famous (and prestigious) examples is [The Open University](http://www.open.ac.uk/) in the UK. You will probably have to take prerequisite courses in high school level material before you'll be allowed to do a Bachelors or similar.

"Brick and Mortar" universities, in general, will not accept you though.

Comment: That's very helpful, i didn't realize that they were Open Universities, i'll check it out